# No Package mysql server available

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, centos, whm

I want to install mysqli on my Linode server but when i run following command

```
yum install mysql-server
```

It gives me following error message:

```
Loaded plugins : fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
*base : mirrors.XXXXX.com
*extras: mirrors.linode.com
*updates : mirrors.linode.com
No package php-mysqli available
Error : Nothing to do
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a duplicate of [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/414486/trying-to-install-phpmyadmin-on-centos-mysqli-missing)

Try using `yum install mysql-server php5X-mysqli` where X matches your minor PHP version.

Comment: Thanks Andy for your answer but it is giving error message command not found.

Comment: Check my edit - you need to yum install the packages.  Remember to replace the X with the correct version for your php